# Stop a C# thread that is not in a while loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll

I've searched around to find the best way to terminate a non UI thread. What I found is that, in short, the thread is in a while loop and you simply set the while loop condition to false to make the thread exit the loop:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.80).aspx
```

Fine but my thread is not in a while loop. The thread is started and then its dispatcher is used. It's actually a thread in a C# dll. The dll itself is using a second C++ dll through a SWIG interface. Long story short, I need a dispatcher.

Now before going further, I would like to mention that everything works fine. But the only way I found to stop the dll thread is by calling Thread.Abort(). I would like to this in a more graceful way.

From the UI thread, that uses the C# dll, an instance of the dll class is created:

```
    public CSomethingDll()
    {
        // This is the dll class constructor.
        using (m_startEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            m_mainSdkThread = new Thread(DllThreadEntryPoint);
            m_mainSdkThread.Name = "DLL THREAD";
            m_mainSdkThread.Start(m_startEvent);

            m_startEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    [STAThreadAttribute]
    public void DllThreadEntryPoint (object o)
    {
        m_dispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        (o as ManualResetEvent).Set();

        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();

        // The dispatcher is now running and ready for calls to BeginInvoke().
    }
```

The dispatcher of the dll thread is now running. The UI thread can now initialize the dll by calling the InitializeA method of the dll:

```
    public void InitializeA()
    {
        m_dispatcher.BeginInvoke(EvInitialize);
    }
```

Now, when the UI thread is terminating, when the application is closing, the UI thread calls the FinalizeA method:

```
    public void FinalizeA()
    {
        m_dispatcher.BeginInvoke(EvFinalize);
    }
```

Inside the dll thread, stuff is done to terminate everything and release the resources. Everything works fine. But the only way I found to stop the dll thread is by calling Thread.Abort():

```
m_dispatcher.Thread.Abort();
```

Now, is there some trick to stop the dll thread through the Dispatcher? Some way to stop the dispatcher that will then terminate the associated thread?

Thanks!

Comment: Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()?

Comment: Unless the thread has some method to respond to a cancellation request, aborting I believe is the only way to terminate it. If you want it to be handled gracefully on the thread side, code needs to be added inside the method the thread is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you terminate your UI thread, do you properly exit your dispatcher?

You really need [to call `Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.exitallframes(v=vs.110).aspx) so that the `Run` method exits.

Comment: The UI thread belongs to a regular C# WPF application. So nothing is done mannually to stop the UI thread.

Thanks for the tip, it works great :-)